# How to add chars before and after each element within a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I'm trying to add a `\` before a `.` within a string (so I can use it as parameter to RegEx search)

So far my string is an IP: .e.g example:

```
string str = "255.255.255.252";
```

Or

```
string str = "127.0.0.1";
```

I would like the output to be:

```
   255\.255\.255\.252
```

Or

```
   127\.0\.0\.1
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you've included the regex and split tags, but a simple `string.Replace` call should do it...

Comment: The string.Replace Worked.

Comment: @Mattlinux1 I've edited the question and added "regex" back as you had it originally and also accepted my answer with `Regex.Escape` - feel free to revert if it does not match your intention. (Side note: avoid adding tags like "C#" in title)

Comment: That's fine by me also that's some great advice, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `str = str.Replace(".","\\.");` should work for this exact case, consider using existing method to escape strings to use as regular expression - [Regex.Escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

I managed to Implement the code by using, string.Replace:

```
        string str = "255.255.255.252";
        string strOut = str.Replace(".", @"\.");
        Console.WriteLine(strOut);
```

As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet

Comment: upvote for figuring it out (: - with **Jon Skeet** suggestion, yay!

Comment: +1 for getting it working *and* posting the answer. Don't forget to accept it when the time limit passes :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string ip = "255.255.255.252";
string[] temp  = str.Split('.');
string answer = string.Join("\\.",temp);
Console.WriteLine(answer);
```